# Mathematical Induction to Prove Binary Search for First Occurrence of an Element in a Sorted Array

Tags: solution-verification, induction, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

$\newcommand{\cardinal}[1]{\abs{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\cardinal}[1]{\abs{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}$
$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}$
$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
$\newcommand{\domain}[1]{\operatorname{dom}\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\range}[1]{\operatorname{range}\left(#1\right)}$

I am trying to prove some classic algorithms in computer science, e.g., binary search for first occurrence of an element in a sorted array. Here is my formalization of the problem:

Let $a$ be a non-decreasing sequence such that $\domain{a} = \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $\range{a} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $f$ be a function such that $\domain{f} = \mathbb{Z}^{+} \times \left(\left\{-1\right\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^{+}\right)$ and $\range{f} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. Further, for any $l \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $h \in \left\{-1\right\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^{+}$,

if $l > h$, then $f\left(l, h\right) = -1$;

if $l \leq h$, (the first two points indicate that $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$ is the element sought, and the third point indicate that $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$ is not the element sought),

if $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = x$ and $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} = l$, then $f\left(l, h\right) = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$;

if $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = x$ and $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} > l$ and $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) \neq x$, then $f\left(l, h\right) = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$.
\item if the above two conditions are not met, then

if $x > a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$, $f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1, h\right)$;
\item if $x \leq a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$, $f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right)$.

For any $l, h \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $l \leq h$,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = 
\begin{cases}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}},\ \textrm{there is some } s\ \textrm{such that } l \leq s \leq h \textrm{ and } a\left(s\right) = x,\\
-1,\ \textrm{there is no } s\ \textrm{such that } l \leq s \leq h \textrm{ and } a\left(s\right) = x.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

The following is my proof:

Let $P$ be the predicate that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P\left(n\right)$ if and only if for any $l, h$, if $h - l = n$, then
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = 
\begin{cases}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}},\ \textrm{there is some } s\ \textrm{such that } l \leq s \leq h \textrm{ and } a\left(s\right) = x\\
-1,\ \textrm{there is no } s\ \textrm{such that } l \leq s \leq h \textrm{ and } a\left(s\right) = x
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
We use mathematical induction to prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P\left(n\right)$.

First we prove $P\left(0\right)$. In this case, $l = h$. Accordingly,
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} = l.
\end{equation*}
First we assume that there is some $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$. In this case, it is clear that $a\left(l\right) = a\left(h\right) = x$. Back to definition of $f$, indeed, we have $l \leq h$. As
\begin{equation*}
\frac{l + h}{2} = \frac{l + l}{2} = l
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{l + h}{2} = \frac{h + h}{2} = h,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = a\left(l\right) = x.
\end{equation*}
By definition, we have $f\left(l, h\right) = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$. Indeed,
\begin{equation*}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}.
\end{equation*}
As a result, we have $f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}$.

Next we assume that there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$. In this case,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = 
\begin{cases}
f\left(l + 1, l\right) = -1,\ x > a\left(l\right)\\
f\left(l, l - 1\right) = -1,\ x \leq a\left(l\right).
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
We conclude that that in this case, $f\left(l, h\right) = -1$.

Consequently, $P\left(0\right)$ holds. Next, assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for any $m$, if $m \leq n$, $P\left(m\right)$ holds. We wish to prove $P\left(n + 1\right)$. Let $l, h \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $h - l = n + 1$. It is clear that $l < h$. Again, we divide our discussion into the following two major categories:

there is some $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and that $a\left(s\right) = x$;

there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and that $a\left(s\right) = x$.

First, assume that there is some $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and that $a\left(s\right) = x$. Under this assumption, first assume that $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = x$ and $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} = l$. As $l < h$, we have $h = l + 1$. By definition, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = l.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, indeed,
\begin{equation*}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} = l.
\end{equation*}
Thus, in this case, $f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}$. Next, assume that $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = x$ and $\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} > l$ and $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) \neq x$. By definition, we have $f\left(l, h\right) = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$. On the other hand, as $a$ is sorted, $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right) = x$ and $a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) \neq x$, it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} = \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}.
\end{equation*}
Next, assume that the two conditions do not hold. We consider $x > a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$ and $x \leq a\left(\frac{l + h}{2}\right)$. In the first case, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1, h\right).
\end{equation*}
It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
h - \left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1\right) \leq n.
\end{equation*}
By induction hypothesis,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1, h\right) = \min\left\{s \vert \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1 \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, as
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} \neq \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
x > a\left(\frac{l + h}{2}\right),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1 \leq \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} \leq h.
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} = \min\left\{s \vert \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} + 1 \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Consequently, in this case,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}.
\end{equation*}
Next, assume that $x \leq a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$. By definition, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right).
\end{equation*}
It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1 - l \leq n.
\end{equation*}
Using induction hypothesis, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) = \min\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1 \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, as
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} \neq \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
x \leq a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right),
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
\min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}} = \min\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1 \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Consequently, in this case,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}.
\end{equation*}

We conclude that if there is some $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and that $a\left(s\right) = x$ and $h - l = n + 1$, then
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = \min{\left\{s \vert l \leq s \leq h \wedge a\left(s\right) = x\right\}}.
\end{equation*}
Next, we assume there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and that $a\left(s\right) = x$ and $h - l = n + 1$.

Under this assumption, by rule of contradiction, it is immediately clear that the first two conditions under $l \leq h$ cannot be met. We first assume that $x > a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$. By definition,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right).
\end{equation*}
As there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$, there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$. As
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1 - l \leq n,
\end{equation*}
by induction hypothesis,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) = -1.
\end{equation*}
Then indeed we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = -1.
\end{equation*}
Next, assume $x \leq a\left(\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}}\right)$. In this case, by definition, we have
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right).
\end{equation*}
Again, it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1 - l \leq n.
\end{equation*}
As there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$, there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$. Thus, by induction hypothesis,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, \floor{\frac{l + h}{2}} - 1\right) = -1.
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
f\left(l, h\right) = -1.
\end{equation*}

We conclude that if there is no $s$ such that $l \leq s \leq h$ and $a\left(s\right) = x$, $f\left(l, h\right) = -1$.

Finally, we conclude that $P\left(0\right)$ and $P\left(n\right)$ leads to $P\left(n + 1\right)$. As a result, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P\left(n\right)$.

I would like verify this proof using mathematical induction on proof of an algorithm in compute science.

Comment: Your formalization looks overly complicated to me. There is fairly wide literature on program specification and verification. A google search for "prove binary search correctness" will get you lots of relevant links.